# TaskCompletionSource<TResult> sem um parâmetro de tipo

Tags: c#, .net, assincronismo, task

A classe `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` necessita de um tipo `TResult`. Dessa maneira, quando preciso utilizar essa classe sem ter um tipo de retorno (`void`), tenho que fazer algo como:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
// ...
tcs.TrySetResult(null);
```

Não sei se esse é o melhor modo de fazer quando o retorno de uma função é somente uma `Task`, sem tipo nenhum. Me parece gambiarra.

Não existe uma `TaskCompletionSource` sem o parâmetro de tipo? Existe outra saída?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem forma melhor atualmente. Não existe `TaskCompletionSource` sem um resultado a ser definido.

O que talvez possa ser um ganho, mas tenho dúvidas é retornar um tipo por valor e não `object` para evitar alocação no *heap*. mas será um ganho muito pequeno e e não sei se gerará alguma consequência em outras partes.

Se quer aprender tudo sobre assincronismo e tarefas do .NET [esse é o cara para seguir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary).

Comment: Já conhecia o Stephen pelo SOen, mas não sabia que era referência de assincronismo no .NET. Vou ler algumas coisas dele.

Comment: Ele é especialista. Claro que tem o Jon Skeet e outros. Tem gente do time do .NET como o Jared Parsons, tinha o Eric Lippert do compilador que fala muito da parte mais conceitual e como o compilador lida com isso. O Joe Duffy era o cara que criou todo TPL.

Answer (score 1):

É *by-design*. Vi no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11969208/non-generic-taskcompletionsource-or-alternative) que existe um [documento da Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957), escrito por Stephen Toub, "The Task-based Asynchronous pattern", que diz:

> There is no non-generic counterpart to
>   `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>`. However, `Task<TResult>` derives from
>   `Task`, and thus the generic `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` can be
>   used for I/O-bound methods that simply return a `Task` by utilizing a
>   source with a dummy `TResult` (`bool` is a good default choice, and if
>   a developer is concerned about a consumer of the `Task` downcasting it
>   to a `Task<TResult>`, a private `TResult` type may be used)

Ali ele diz para utilizar um booleano no tipo, mas o Stephen Cleary não recomenda, já que `object` com o valor `null` tira o significado, e um valor `true` ou `false` deixa algum significado no valor retornado. De qualquer forma, questão de semântica.